# Connect to a VPN using command line

Tags: windows, vpn

I would like to connect to a VPN using command line but I saw that the only way to connect is to have the connection saved, but I would like to do it without having connection saved like that:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32> rasdial [IP or Hostname]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't believe it's possible to connect with a VPN profile that isn't saved, but you can create a connection on the command line with PowerShell, using the [`Add-VpnConnection`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj554824(v=wps.630).aspx) cmdlet specifically.

For example, to create a VPN connection, you might do something like this:

```
Add-VpnConnection -Name 'MyNewVpn' -ServerAddress 'vpn.example.com'
```

Depending on your VPN server, you may need to provide more of the named parameters.

You can then connect to it with `rasdial`:

```
rasdial MyNewVpn myUsername mySuperSecretPassword
```

You can remove the VPN settings with PowerShell's [`Remove-VpnConnection`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj554817):

```
Remove-VpnConnection 'MyNewVpn'
```

Comment: Thanks, accepted the answer. Is is possible to modify the VPN Profile?

Comment: @AnisRétro Yes, using the [`Set-VpnConnection`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj554823) cmdlet. For example, `Set-VpnConnection 'MyNewVpn' -ServerAddress 'new.example.com'` changes the address of the `MyNewVpn` profile to `new.example.com`.